# How to start the app from the beginning login screen when home is pressed?

Tags: java, android, button

I am working on an app what I need is that whenever user press home while running the app and again resume to the app , it must start from the beginning login screen.

I have tried this : Answer from [Resume after pressing 'Home' should start my Startactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593953/resume-after-pressing-home-should-start-my-startactivity?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

But it is not working .can any one help me?

Comment: No..I still want a better solution!If I kill the process onRestart App doesnt work well it closes some screen itself

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you just have to call the 
login screen at onResume....

---

There are mainly two solutions of this problem....

1. the best option is **Override the home Button**
2. or you just have to **kill all parent activities** when home button clicked....

[Override home button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025904/1160282)

See the First answer
this will help u...

You can also do that at resume you have to check which activity was running when home button clicked so you have to kill that activity & start the login activity..
but this will be little complicated while **overriding the home button** is best option..

Comment: Overriding Home Button is not the thing that user want. You may further edit your answer to the exact requirement in the question.

Comment: but in this question user wants to start or resume the app from login page so user should just kill all the activities n start the login or finish the app...

n about home button overriding this is also a good idea to load the app or to resume the app from selected activity...

Comment: Yes, but in your answer I can't see anything related to closing all the Activities.

Comment: I only want to knoe how to kill all actvities

Comment: use this at onResume...

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: In which activity I should use that ?? In one or all activities??

Comment: Killing process forcefully is a bad way.

Comment: u should write this at all activity where there is a possibility of home button clicked....

as the killing process forcefully is a bad way thats why i suggest to override the home button....